# ng2-file-upload multiple files to different URL's, but use same Uploader

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using [ng2-file-upload](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/) to manage file uploading in my **Angular 6** application. What I want to achieve is to be able to upload multiple files using the same **`uploader:FileUploader`** object, but every file should have a different URL.

```
public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader();

<div ng2FileDrop
           [ngClass]="{'dz-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
           (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
           [uploader]="uploader"
           class="fileupload-drop-zone">
        Drop required files here
</div>
```

I am able to use `onBeforeUploadItem` to change the URL of every file right before it gets uploaded.

```
this.uploaderCustomerIdentificaiton.onBeforeUploadItem = (fileItem): any => {
  fileItem.url = newUrl;
  return {fileItem};
};
```

For every file I need to upload, I will have separate (notice that it's the same uploader object).

`<div ng2FileDrop [uploader]="uploader"....</div>`

So every **ng2FileDrop** should have a different URL.